# Android: ImageLoader doesnt work, the placeholder always appears

Tags: android, android-studio, asynchronous, android-drawable

Few days ago i have a project that worked perfectly, after change the project version something changed automatically and the class that i was using to download images async stop working.

I used this tutorial to make my Imageloader: 
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/

Right now i am receiving this warning (i guess that this is the problem):

Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Comment: I would recommend using Picasso: https://github.com/square/picasso
It handles all these things automaticaly

Comment: thanks, Picasso resolved my problem